# Spark Compare two dataframes and find the match count

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark sql dataframs both are not having any unique column. First dataframe contains n-grams, second one contains long text string (blog post). I want to find the matches on df2 and add count in df1.

```
DF1
------------
words
------------
Stack
Stack Overflow
users
spark scala

DF2

--------
POSTS
--------
Hello, Stack overflow users , Do you know spark scala
Spark scala is very fast
Users in stack are good in spark, users


Expected output

  ------------     ---------------
    words            match_count
  ------------    ---------------

    Stack               2           
    Stack Overflow      1
    users               3
    spark scala         1
```

Comment: Any comments on my answer or the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force approach as follows in Scala not working over lines and treating all as lowercase, could all be added but that is for another day. Relies on not trying to examine strings but to define ngrams as that is what it is is, ngrams against ngrams and genning these and then JOINing and counting, whereby inner join only relevant. Some extra data added to prove the matching.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType,ArrayType,LongType,StringType}
import spark.implicits._

// Sample data, duplicates and items to check it works.
val dfPostsInit = Seq(
                  ( "Hello!!, Stack overflow users, Do you know spark scala users."),
                  ( "Spark scala is very fast,"),
                  ( "Users in stack are good in spark"),
                  ( "Users in stack are good in spark"),
                  ( "xy z"),
                  ( "x yz"),
                  ( "ABC"),
                  ( "abc"),
                  ( "XYZ,!!YYY@#$ Hello Bob..."))
                 .toDF("posting")

val dfWordsInit = Seq(("Stack"), ("Stack Overflow"),("users"), ("spark scala"), ("xyz"), ("xy"), ("not found"), ("abc")).toDF("words")
val dfWords     = dfWordsInit.withColumn("words_perm" ,regexp_replace(dfWordsInit("words"), " ", "^")).withColumn("lower_words_perm" ,lower(regexp_replace(dfWordsInit("words"), " ", "^")))

val dfPostsTemp = dfPostsInit.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(0).split("\\W+").toArray )) 
// Tidy Up
val columnsRenamed = Seq("posting", "posting_array") 
val dfPosts = dfPostsTemp.toDF(columnsRenamed: _*)

// Generate Ngrams up to some limit N - needs to be set. This so that we can count properly via a JOIN direct comparison. Can parametrize this in calls below.
// Not easy to find string matching over Array and no other answer presented.
def buildNgrams(inputCol: String = "posting_array", n: Int = 3) = {
  val ngrams = (1 to n).map(i =>
      new NGram().setN(i)
        .setInputCol(inputCol).setOutputCol(s"${i}_grams")
  )
  new Pipeline().setStages((ngrams).toArray)
}

val suffix:String = "_grams"
var i_grams_Cols:List[String] = Nil
for(i <- 1 to 3) {
   val iGCS = i.toString.concat(suffix)
   i_grams_Cols = i_grams_Cols ::: List(iGCS)
}     
// Generate data for checking against later from via rows only and thus not via columns, positional dependency counts, hence permutations. 
val dfPostsNGrams = buildNgrams().fit(dfPosts).transform(dfPosts)

val dummySchema = StructType(
    StructField("phrase", StringType, true) :: Nil)
var dfPostsNGrams2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], dummySchema)
for (i <- i_grams_Cols) {
  val nameCol = col({i})
  dfPostsNGrams2 = dfPostsNGrams2.union (dfPostsNGrams.select(explode({nameCol}).as("phrase")).toDF )
 }

val dfPostsNGrams3     = dfPostsNGrams2.withColumn("lower_phrase_concatenated",lower(regexp_replace(dfPostsNGrams2("phrase"), " ", "^"))) 

val result = dfPostsNGrams3.join(dfWords, col("lower_phrase_concatenated") === 
col("lower_words_perm"), "inner")  
              .groupBy("words_perm", "words")
              .agg(count("*").as("match_count"))

result.select("words", "match_count").show(false)
```

returns:

```
+--------------+-----------+
|words         |match_count|
+--------------+-----------+
|spark scala   |2          |
|users         |4          |
|abc           |2          |
|Stack Overflow|1          |
|xy            |1          |
|Stack         |3          |
|xyz           |1          |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Interesting problem escaping a few people's attention. Shows the power of SPARK/SCALA.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `join-groupBy-count` will do:

```
df1
    .join(df2, expr("lower(posts) rlike lower(words)"))
    .groupBy("words")
    .agg(count("*").as("match_count"))
```

Comment: It seems not. Consider a line like:  "Hello, Stack overflow users , Do you know spark scala users". It does not count users twice and in fact what about users users? --> edge case

Comment: @thebluephantom, You assume that the OP wants to count multiple occurrences of `words` inside `posts`, however it's not clear from the question that that what he actually wants. In fact, the provided example implies that there is no such need.

Comment: I am not a clairvoyant, so I think that would need to be resolved. I can see why he asked it and think why -1's.

Comment: All I am trying to get the document frequency from the n-grams. So I have one dataframe with collections of terms or bigrams in other df. I have only post descriptions. So I want to take each word in df1 and see the number of occurrence in the second df from all the rows.

Comment: Still hard for me to follow. I have used this as a basis for an interesting, if not overkill approach. Nearly finished.

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub: I just edited question, I added word "users" in 3rd post. So now count should 3 for users. because users terms appears 1 time in first and 2 time in 3rd. Hope this explanation makesense . You results just counting the number of rows that match occurs

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas features in pyspark. Here is my solution below

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(['Stack','Stack Overflow','users','spark scala'])
>>> data1 = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(x))
>>> df1=spark.createDataFrame(data1,['words'])
>>> df1.show()
+--------------+
|         words|
+--------------+
|         Stack|
|Stack Overflow|
|         users|
|   spark scala|
+--------------+

>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize([
...     'Hello, Stack overflow users , Do you know spark scala',
...     'Spark scala is very fast',
...     'Users in stack are good in spark'
...     ])
>>> data2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: Row(x))
>>> df2=spark.createDataFrame(data2,['posts'])
>>> df2.show()
+--------------------+
|               posts|
+--------------------+
|Hello, Stack over...|
|Spark scala is ve...|
|Users in stack ar...|
+--------------------+

>>> dfPd1 = df1.toPandas()
>>> dfPd2 = df2.toPandas().apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
>>> 
>>> words = dict((x,0) for x in dfPd1['words'])
>>> 
>>> for i in words:
...     x = dfPd2['posts'].str.contains(i.lower()).sum()
...     if i in words:
...         words[i] = x
... 
>>> 
>>> words
{'Stack': 2, 'Stack Overflow': 1, 'users': 2, 'spark scala': 2}
>>> 
>>> data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(words, orient='index').reset_index()
>>> data.columns = ['words','match_count']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
>>> df.show()
+--------------+-----------+
|         words|match_count|
+--------------+-----------+
|         Stack|          2|
|Stack Overflow|          1|
|         users|          2|
|   spark scala|          2|
+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hello Ali, Thanks for answering, I am looking for solution in apache scala not in pyspark. Any I will try to convert your code into scala

Comment: @Gowri  _Please post your effort when done for the benefit of others. I am also doing a solution, so keen to compare. The -1's were invalid as we see.

Comment: I am not expert on scala side. Maybe someone can convert it to scala. This is the reason why I added the python code. I hope it would help