# PySpark compare two dataframes and find the match count

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, for-loop, pyspark, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 pyspark dataframes, after some manipulation consisting of 1 column each, but both are different length. dataframe 1 is an ingredient name, dataframe 2 contains rows of long strings of ingredients.

DATAFRAME 1:

```
ingcomb.show(10,truncate=False)
+---------------------------------+
|products                         |
+---------------------------------+
|rebel crunch granola             |
|creamed honey                    |
|mild cheddar with onions & chives|
|berry medley                     |
|sweet relish made with sea salt  |
|spanish peanuts                  |
|stir fry seasoning mix           |
|swiss all natural cheese         |
|yellow corn meal                 |
|shredded wheat                   |
+---------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

DATAFRAME 2:

```
reging.show(10, truncate=30)
+------------------------------+
|                   ingredients|
+------------------------------+
|apple bean cookie fruit kid...|
|bake bastille day bon appét...|
|dairy fennel gourmet new yo...|
|bon appétit dairy free dinn...|
|bake bon appétit california...|
|bacon basil bon appétit foo...|
|asparagus boil bon appétit ...|
|cocktail party egg fruit go...|
|beef ginger gourmet quick &...|
|dairy free gourmet ham lunc...|
+------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I need to create a loop (any other suggestions are welcome too!) to loop through dataframe 1 and compare the values to dataframe strings via "like" and give me total count of matches.

Desired outcome:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|         ingredients|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|rebel crunch granola|  183|
|creamed honey       |   87|
|berry medley        |   67|
|spanish peanuts     |   10|
+--------------------+-----+
```

I know that the following code works:

```
reging.filter("ingredients like '%sugar%'").count()
```

and was trying to implement something like

```
for i in ingcomb:
    x = reging.select("ingredients").filter("ingredients like '%i%'").count()
```

But cannot get pyspark to consider 'i' as a value from ingcomb instead of the character i.

I have tried the solutions from 
[Spark Compare two dataframe and find the match count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566310/spark-compare-two-dataframe-and-find-the-match-count)
but unfortunately they do not work.
I am running this in GCP and get an error when I try to run toPandas - due to permissions cannot install pandas.

Comment: Hi @ValA do you know approximately how big the two datasets are?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrosBiratsis one dataframe had 249,245 rows and the other 20,057 rows. The data in total is a little over 1 GB, so not that large at all.

Answer (score 0):

We were actually able to do a work around, where we will get counts within the dataframe first and then match with a join later. Please feel free to give better suggestions. Newbies to coding here.

```
counts= reging.select(f.explode("array(Ingredients)").alias('col'))
.groupBy('col').count().orderBy("count", ascending=False)
```